# How are the indeterminate forms, determined?

Tags: limits, definition, indeterminate-forms

There are seven expressions commonly considered as indeterminate forms: $\frac{0}{0}$, $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, $0\times \infty$, $\infty -\infty$, $0^{0}$, $1^{\infty}$ and $\infty^{0}$; since as I understand, they can all equal more than one thing dependant on the situation.

- How were these discovered/defined as the base cases?
- Aren't some of them the same expression with little manipulation? ($\frac{\infty}{\infty} = \frac{1}{\infty}\times \infty = 0\times\infty$)
- Does the defining of them actually matter apart from recognising when you have to be careful determining a limit?

Comment: No idea, yes, no.

Comment: They are not the "base cases". It's just that we have a set of five binary operations and we are quite naturally looking for ways to extend them to $(\Bbb R\cup\{+\infty\})\times(\Bbb R\cup\{+\infty\})$ in a way which extends the usual operations on $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ (or the likes of it) in a way which commutes with sequential limits. It turns out these cases do not work and, as you've noticed, some of them are redundant. In principle, we could have a preference or different binary operations hich do not behave well with limits at $\infty$, and thus have more "base cases".

Comment: In fact, all of them are equivalent to one another using some manipulation. $0\times \infty$ and $\frac\infty\infty$ you already noticed. Taking logarithm transforms $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac\infty\infty$ (and $0\times \infty$) into $\infty - \infty$. Logarithms also make the exponential forms into $0\times \infty$ ($-0\times \infty$ in the case of $0^0$).

Comment: Arthur, indeed I just mentioned the simplest

Comment: You don't have to "define" indeterminate forms, because they are simply the result of ill-conducted operations i.e we have definitions for the operations with numbers and some cases elude these definitions.
I am teaching calculus to first year students and the "indeterminate forms" are simply a thing of convinience without having to spend time to explain the reason these operations don't work. Instead, I tell them that when we arrive at such operations in limit exercises then we have to manipulate the expression in some way (and I show them how, as well).

Comment: Enter the measure theory or real analysis courses, however, they will happily indulge in telling you all about it :)